Issue regarding self repeated .vasp structure of engineered graphite/graphene
When engineers the graphite and save it as.vasp format, it will give self periodically repeated structure. Still, the size of the cell is the same, but the structure repeated itself by huge numbers in all three directions making it difficult to visualize. Could, anybody help to figure out this issue,and this only happens with graphite/graphene-based systems.
Thank You!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

+1. Welcome to our community.  Could you add the image of the structures?
